# MySQL Regular Expression equivalent with NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column which has data like this pattern : `0#0#0#0#0`

Sometime, the data change to : `1#0#0#0#0` or `1#2#0#0#0` or `1#2#3#0#0`

My question is to search with regular expression which the first and second number is not zero.

my query was :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^...#0#0#0$'
```

But the result which has data `1#0#0#0#0` and `1#2#0#0#0` is selected.

I want just `1#2#0#0#0` selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[1-9]#[1-9]#0#0#0$'
```

You can test the regex with this tool: http://regexr.com/3a9hi

[image: Tested with regexr.com]

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this with `substring_index()` instead?

```
where substring_index(column, '#', 1) <> '0' and
      substring_index(substring_index(column, '#', 2), '#', -1) <> '0'
```

Comment: this doesnt valid where we have `1#2#3#0#0` data

Comment: @FebriantoArifRakhman . . . Your question was "My question is to search with regular expression which the first and second number is not zero.".  It is not clear that you require the other values to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[1-9]#[1-9]#0#0#0$
```

or

```
^[^0]#[^0]#0#0#0$
```

I guess this should do it.